# laravel : access a property without declaring it

Tags: laravel, properties, model

in some laravel based packages there is a reference to properties that are not declared but are the name of that model's table column .

**tickets** table:

```
  id 
  name
  content
```

and **Ticket** model:

```
 class Ticket extends Model {

//there is no "protected $content;" defined inside model
$this->content = foo;
 ......

}
```

does model properties are created dynamically based on model table columns?

Comment: Yes, laravel's eloquent maps the column names to attributes on the model. This is the typical behaviour of an ORM (Object Relational Mapper). see: http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/php/the-benefits-of-using-object-relational-mapping-in-php/

Answer (score 2):

You need to set $guarded or $fillable https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment in your model. For example:

```
class Ticket extends model {
  protected $guarded =[];
}
```

This let's you access all table columns and update them.

```
class Ticket extends model {
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'content'];
}
```

This let's you access columns `name` and `content` and udpate only them.

Comment: thanks.so after setting $guarded  or $fillable is it possible to do: `$this->content = foo ` , note im not asking about  : `$ticket->content`

Comment: In your model exampleFunction() { $this->foo = 'bar'; $this->save(); }

Answer (score 0):

Model attributes are implicitly declared depending on the mapped database table columns.

youcan explicitly declare the matching table

```
protected $table = 'tablename';
```